# template specialization : does not match any template declaration

Tags: c++, templates

When I study the template specialization, I use a very simple example, but I still got error.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class chrrr{
    public:
    T chgchr(T c);  
};

template < class T> 
T chrrr<T>::chgchr(T c){
    return c+1; 
}

template <>
class chrrr<char>{
    public:
    char chgchr(char c);    
};
template <>
char chrrr<char>::chgchr(char c){
    return c+2; 
}



using namespace std;

int main(){
    char a='a';
    int i=1;

    chrrr<int> it;
    chrrr<char> ch;
    cout<<ch.chgchr(a)<<endl;
    cout<<it.chgchr(i)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The error said:

```
line 20: error: template-id ‘chgchr<>’ for ‘char chrrr<char>::chgchr(char)’ does not match any template declaration
```

I wonder why it dose not match? And if I define chgchr in class definition body rather than out side, it works very well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have explicitly specialized the class, resulting in a fully instantiated type called `chrrr<char>`. You don't need to give the template arguments when defining the member function. Simply:

```
char chrrr<char>::chgchr(char c){
    return c+2; 
}
```

However, it seems you are specializing the whole class just to specialize a single function. You can do that with:

```
template <class T>
class chrrr {
    public:
    T chgchr(T c);  
};

template <class T> 
T chrrr<T>::chgchr(T c){
    return c+1; 
}

// Explicitly specialize for the member function
template <>
char chrrr<char>::chgchr(char c){
    return c+2; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! SFTRABBIT!
I find both you and James answer very useful and they give me two way to define template class method

Answer (score 6):

Specialized class templates result in a normal class with
a funny name, and not a template.  When you specialize
`chrrr<char>`, it is no longer a template, and the
implementation of its class members are *not* template
specializations.  So you should simply write:

```
char
chrrr<char>::chgchr( char c ) ...
```

The `template<>` you put in front says that there is still
another template to be specialized, which is not the case.

Comment: If it's not the book your using, I would strongly recommend _C++ Templates: the Complete Guide_, by David Vandevoorde and Nicolai Josuttis.  It covers all of the details, and still manages to remain extremely readable.

Comment: Ok, I will find it and see if I can be able to understand those concept. Thanks, James!